# Problem passing a parameter to a different class

Tags: java, android, methods, parameters, android-3.0-honeycomb

I've got a rather peculiar problem. I am trying to pass a number of parameters to a method in a different class, and three out of the four parameters are being passed just fine. The fourth, however, is returning 0 (zero) regardless of what I seem to do.

I am initializing the second class, ImageLoader, without any issues.

Here's the call in question - I've added comments to explain my problem:

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(coverFileNames.get(position), Main.this, (ImageView) convertView, position); // coverFileNames.get(position) works great and returns the correct filename based on the position - position on its own, however, doesn't!
```

And here's the DisplayImage method:

```
public int position;

public void DisplayImage(String fileUrl, Activity activity, ImageView imageView, final int pos) {
                position = pos; // this is 0 no matter what I do
                imageViews.put(imageView, fileUrl);
                queuePhoto(fileUrl, activity, imageView);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.noposterlarge);
            }
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here's the GetView method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = (ImageView) new ImageView(Main.this);
            }

            // Create new file for the file path of the movie
            File file = new File(videoUrls.get(position));

            // Create variables for potential custom art check
            boolean potentialImage = false;
            String ImageFile = null;
            String[] potentialImageFiles = new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".")) + ".jpg",
                    file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".")) + ".jpeg",
                    file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".")) + ".JPG",
                    file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".")) + ".JPEG"};

            // Check if each file exists and return if one does
            for (String potentialFile : potentialImageFiles) {
                if (!potentialImage) {
                    if (new File(potentialFile).exists()) {
                        potentialImage = true;
                        ImageFile = potentialFile;
                    }
                }
            }

            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;

            // Check if there's a custom cover art
            if (potentialImage) {
                Log.d("TEST", "POS: " + position); // this returns the correct value
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(ImageFile, Main.this, (ImageView) convertView, position);
            } else {
                Log.d("TEST", "POS: " + position); // this returns the correct value
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(coverFileNames.get(position), Main.this, (ImageView) convertView, position);
            }

            return convertView;
        }
```

And again, here's the DisplayImage method:

```
public void DisplayImage(String fileUrl, Activity activity, ImageView imageView, final int pos) {
            Log.v("Testing", "position = " + pos); // This returns 0, which is not correct
            imageViews.put(imageView, fileUrl);
            queuePhoto(fileUrl, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.noposterlarge);
        }
```

Comment: why don't you tell what you do to get the variable "position"....?

Comment: It's the position variable from the GetView method in a BaseAdapter. Sorry I forgot. But it's perfectly valid and I have no problems using it in the GetView method.

Comment: @Dave
It was just for testing purposes to see if it changed anything - it didn't :(

Comment: are you initialising "position" some where, i mean in getView() method. seems like you are passing it without initialisation.

Comment: Have you printed out the value of position before the call to DisplayImage?

Comment: @ntc
The position variable is initialized in the GetView method.

Comment: @Dave
Yep, I did and it returned the correct value every time. And the coverFileNames.get(position) is also returning the correct file name.

Comment: @Michell Bak and what are you doing in DisplayImage to show that the value is always 0?

Comment: @Dave
I've tried printing the value using both Log and system.out.println.

Comment: Printing which value? And on what line are you printing it?

Comment: @Dave Here's my code:

  `public void DisplayImage(String fileUrl, Activity activity, ImageView imageView, final int pos) {
   Log.v("Testing", "position = " + pos);
   position = pos;
   imageViews.put(imageView, fileUrl);
   queuePhoto(fileUrl, activity, imageView);
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.noposterlarge);
  }`

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger and placing a breakpoint and examining the values as you step over them?

Comment: why don't you post full code of this class....

Comment: There is nothing wrong ! @Michell please show me the block of code where you call `imageLoader.DisplayImage(coverFileNames.get(position), Main.this, (ImageView) convertView, position);` Is it a function? edit your question

Comment: Can you add your full code around these areas with all your calls to logging etc. I get the feeling there must be something else going on that is not shown in your snippet above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simply impossible

Add to top of `DisplayImage`

```
Log.v("DisplayImage", "position = " + position);
```

---

If it is `0`

Change the calling code from

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(coverFileNames.get(position), Main.this, (ImageView) convertView, position);
```

to

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(coverFileNames.get(position), Main.this, (ImageView) convertView, 2);
```

Now, will it show `2`? ***It must***

---

It means that in your calling code in the line `imageLoader.DisplayImage()` position has always been `0` for some reason.

`coverFileNames.get(position)` is always returning the String at `position=0`

---

Try removing the `final` modifier from your DisplayImage function

```
public void DisplayImage(String fileUrl, Activity activity, ImageView imageView, int pos)
```

Comment: 08-09 10:27:42.820: VERBOSE/DisplayImage(29966): position = 0

It's extremely strange and I have no idea why it's happening.

Comment: Adding that to the 'top' of DisplayImage will obviously write 0, because 'position' hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Yep, that's what I though, so I changed it to:
`Log.v("DisplayImage", "position = " + pos);`

Comment: @Sherif
Yep, that changes it to 2.

Comment: Ok  I edited.. It is clear that position is zero all the times and you are wrong about `coverFileNames.get(position)` It is not working

Comment: @SherifNope - coverFileNames.get(position) is always returning the correct string at the given position. The position variable works in coverFileNames.

Comment: It's an ArrayList of strings with filenames to images. This works without any issues.

Comment: That's the second class, in which DisplayImage is. I am building a gridview with lazy loading.

Comment: listen Are you sure `Log.v("Testing", "position = " + pos);` is outputting something wrong? OR are you looking at the picture to verify?

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely positive. Not a doubt in my mind. However, looking at the Logcat entries, it seems that it reloading everything for some reason, and that's causing it to return 0. I'll check it out and get back to you.

Comment: It seems like it's calling GetView() on all items twice - any ideas to why this is happening?

Comment: listen GetView is called always (everytime you scroll for example) I am sure in the logs there is `position = something not 0` somewhere! Search all the logcats. Maybe it is by coincidence that GetView is calling position zero at last (or at first)

Comment: Yeah, the LogCat is prompting correct logs, i.e. position = n, and runs through all the 18 shown views, but after that it goes through them all again and returns position = 0.

Comment: ok then it is okay! because GetView is a rendering function (it is called everytime the UI thread needs a view from your adapter)

Comment: Yeah, but I need to use the position to get some data, and if it returns 0, then I can't do that.

Comment: the function will return all the values ! so if your adapter has 20 items GetView will be called for position 0 through 19 . You chould implement the arraylist in a way that it does not just get bigger (In other words you must know that GetView may be called twice or more for the same position)

Comment: I just solved the problem using a different way, but thanks for all your help - it's been great! That's why I love Stackoverflow :)